# How to set value to input file with jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I know I can't set a value to an input file.
But how can I solve this problem when I'm testing with jest?

I have an input file that is required (using vee-validate) and when I run a test there is an error saying that the field is required.

Is there a way to solve this problem ?
How to set a value to an input file on tests ?
I can't even use v-model on input file.

input file:

```
<input
        id="image"
        ref="file"
        type="file"
        @change="handleFileUpload"
      >
```

Comment: Can you update the question to show the component code that you're testing?

Comment: question updated